# SOQL query according to date in salesforce

Tags: apex, soql, query

My Requirement is "the records should be considered next only when they complete 12 months" and this is monthly exercise so if i query the data from database it should not include the previous data.

suppose I have `sent_Date__C` custom  field(which stores date of record used or query date), when ever i query data i need to use `sent_Date__C` field and get data from database.

the previous data should be included when the difference of `sent_Date__C` field and tdys date should be 1 year.

I want the data using SOQL.

Comment: Have you searched [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/) for SOQL tutorials and looked at the [SOQL documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm)?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to show the community *what you've tried* and *where you're stuck*. See [ask] and [help/on-topic] for more about the SFSE format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be more precise about the timeframe you're looking at (are you looking for records that are exactly 1 year old? ones that are up to 1 year and 1 week old? etc...)

The [SOQL and SOSL Date Formats and Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) page is a good place to start looking. Even though it's not documented, the `N_WEEKS_AGO:<integer>` literal may be useful here.